# add column based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
PersonID    DateKey   C/L
   1       20140903    8 
   1       20140904    null
   1       20140906    10 
   1       20140908    null  
   2       20140903    18 
   2       20140904    null
   2       20140906    30 
   2       20140908    null
```

I need to add another column and repeat the value of `[C/L]` the resultant table should be as below:

```
PersonID    DateKey   C/L      C/L_New
   1       20140903    8          8
   1       20140904    null       8
   1       20140906    10         10
   1       20140908    null       10
   2       20140903    18         18
   2       20140904    null       18
   2       20140906    30         30
   2       20140908    null       30
```

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this (presuming `DateKey` is a date or datetime column):

```
SELECT PersonID,    
       DateKey,
       [C/L],
       [C/L_New] = ISNULL([C/L], (SELECT TOP 1 t2.[C/L]
                                  FROM dbo.TableName t2
                                  WHERE t2.PersonID = t.PersonID
                                  AND   t2.DateKey <= t.DateKey
                                  AND   t2.[C/L] IS NOT NULL
                                  ORDER BY DateKey DESC))
FROM dbo.TableName t
Order By PersonID, DateKey
```

Edit: [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51800/3/0)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want the value from the previous row if the value of the current row is `NULL`.

From *SQL Server 2012* you can use the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function:

```
SELECT PersonID
      ,DateKey
      ,[C/L]
      ,COALESCE([C/L], LAG([C/L], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, DateKey)) AS [C/L_New]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: May want `OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY DateKey)`.

Comment: Yeah, you may not get desirable results if the first record for a person has a `NULL` for `C/L`.  It will pull the last `C/L` of the previous person.  That probably doesn't make sense.